# rvest: how to capture a string after a specific text

Tags: r, rvest

I am on page: https://aplikacje.nfz.gov.pl/umowy/AgreementsPlan/GetPlans?ROK=2017&ServiceType=03&ProviderId=104056&OW=01&OrthopedicSupply=False&Code=3202801&AgreementTechnicalCode=1030545

There is the header with some values

```
Rok: 2017
Oddział wojewódzki: Dolnośląski Oddział Wojewódzki Narodowego Funduszu  Zdrowia
Kod świadczeniodawcy: 3202801
Nazwa świadczeniodawcy: CHIRPLAST SPÓŁKA JAWNA IWONA RYCHLIK, DARIUSZ RYCHLIK
Kod umowy: 03/1/3202801/01/2017/01
Nazwa rodzaju świadczenia: Leczenie szpitalne
```

I would like to scrape only the value that stands after "Kod umowy"

```
03/1/3202801/01/2017/01
```

I understand I need to fill in the parameter

```
 kod_umowy <- html_nodes(pg, ????? )
```

for x-path or css node, but there is no identifier (so it seems to me) that would identify the location but a string that precedes the value.

Is it possible to grab the first string that appears after a specific string? (probably in the case of this page it means going accross/ignoring some html syntax, to get to the next string in the line).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(rvest)

pg <- read_html("https://aplikacje.nfz.gov.pl/umowy/AgreementsPlan/GetPlans?ROK=2017&ServiceType=03&ProviderId=104056&OW=01&OrthopedicSupply=False&Code=3202801&AgreementTechnicalCode=1030545")

html_nodes(pg, xpath=".//div[contains(., 'Kod umowy:') and contains(@class, 'col-sm-3')]/following-sibling::div[2]") %>% 
  html_text()
## [1] "03/1/3202801/01/2017/01"
```